# iOS15 otpauth opening Apple Password Manager instead of Google Auth? iOS 14 works correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a small issue where otpauth (LSApplicationQueriesSchemes) is opening Apple Password Manager on iOS 15 but I would like to open any other 2fa app(Google auth, etc...) on the phone. On iOS14, it works as expected.

Shouldn't apple-otpauth open the Apple Password Manager and not otpauth? How would I open another other 2fa app like Google Auth?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

iOS 15 includes a built in [Password Authenticator](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/07/ios-15-built-in-password-authenticator/). Google Auth navigates to Apple Password Manager now.

After 2fa is set up on an iPhone, you can no longer disable it. [source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915#:%7E:text=If%20you%20recently%20updated%20your,features%20that%20require%20higher%20security.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I noticed that as well but was not sure if there was a way by pass Apple Password Manager or disabled.

Comment: I wish there was a way to disable it, but couldn't find any info on that

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 16 (16.3.1 in my case), you can choose which app to open with the otpauth:// in the password options menu.
(Setting > Password > Password Options > SET UP VERIFICATION CODES USING:)